# Dependent drop down of Country, State, City in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown

What is the best way to make a dependent drop down of Country, State and City in codeigniter?
It should display the list of all countries automatically not manual entries. The cities and state is further shown according to selection of the user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question asks to "GIMMY THE CODEZ", but that doesn't work here and will get your question **down-voted** then put **on-hold** and eventually **closed**. You need to write your own code and once you run into a specific problem then use Stack Overflow to ask for help for that specific problem. As your question is written now it is way to broad. Please read 
[**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site
[**Taking the Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: see also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/603/is-a-country-state-city-database-available

Comment: This is a common issue many developers faced so i asked. Because i have to implement it in my new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sample code for depended drop down for `state` and `city`. In this example you can get `cities` of respected `state` using `ajax`. You can refer it and enhance this as per your requirement to add `country`.

```
$(document).on('change','#state',function () {
    $('#city').remove();
    if($(this).val() != 'none')
    {
        var state_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'page.php',
            data: { state_id: state_id },
            success: function (city_response) {
                if(city_response == '')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var city = '<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">';
                    city += '<option value="-----">Please select any City</option>';
                    $.each(city_response, function (ck, cv) {
                        city += '<option value="' + cv['city_id'] + '">' + cv['city_name'] + '</option>';
                    });
                    city += '</select>';
                    $("#city_div").css('display', 'block');
                    $('#cities').append(city);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        $("#city_div").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.